# What tool/tools was this person using in the video?

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to create a baymax funko pop in blender for a project, and the way I'm doing it seems really inefficent and unsatisfacotory (approximating the shapes with the sculpting tool). When I looked up tutorials on how to get better at blender, I found this video where it shows him deforming a sphere but extruding(?) the top vertex, but whenever I try to replicate this it only deforms the vertex I selected rather than the entire sphere like in the video.

Video for reference: https://youtu.be/LwqeZq35ojk?t=21

Also side question what tools is this person using to deform his sphere in the shape of baymax's head 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gf53u4iuDtw

Comment: To include adjacent vertices, switch on "Proportional Edit"  As you drag the vertice selected a white circle will show you the area of influence.  I use the Page-up and Page-down keys to adjust this.

Comment: Okay thanks for that, but whenever I try to change the size of a face/verice/edge it only changes the expands the surface area of the face rather than pulling it out of the sphere and deforming the rest of it like in the video. Is there a setting I'm missing?

Comment: It sounds like you should be using Grab rather than scale with proportional editing, though scale will work with proportional editing.